# React Native - ScrollableTabView slow when switching tabs on Android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Recently started to learn React Native. I'm using this "react-native-scrollable-tab-view" component and inside I placed "react-native-complete-flatlist" component. I got around 10 tabs(dynamic) and switching tabs is slow.

Here is my code:

```
<ScrollableTabView 
scrollWithoutAnimation={true}
renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
onChangeTab={(event)=> this.changeTab(event.i)}
>
    {tabArray.map((data, index) => {
     return <View key={index+1} tabLabel={data} style={{flex:1}}>

         <View style={styles.container}>

          <Spinner visible={this.state.spinner} />

          <CompleteFlatList
          searchKey={['key','imageKey']}
          //highlightColor="yellow"
          pullToRefreshCallback={() => {
          // alert('refreshing');
          }}
          data={FlatListItems}
          ref={c => this.completeFlatList = c}
          renderSeparator={null}
          renderItem={this.cell}
          onEndReached={() => console.log("reach end")}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0}
          //stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
          />  

        </View>
      </View> 
     })}

</ScrollableTabView>
```

I turned JS Dev Mode -> OFF (Android) it was better than previous. Still, the lag is noticeable when switching tab. 
Kindly provide any suggestions on improving this lag?

Comment: Can you create an example for us?

Comment: apart from "renderItem" in completeflatlist I have added the remaining code from my working page? Need that  "renderItem" block ? Is that enough?

Comment: I meant an online snippet using something like https://codesandbox.io

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@mittech/testtab

Comment: try and add 'prerenderingSiblingsNumber={Infinity}' to ScrollableTabView